# Relationship between user and store

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, php-7.1

I need to create a relationship between user and many stores. I have created a three models

`Store Model`

```
id name email            phone       info
1  xyz  xyz@gmail.com    9329292922  Small Store
2  abc  abc@gmail.com    9494949449  Some Store
```

`User Model`

```
id name email                  
1  ewd  ewd@gmail.com   
2  xcv  xcv@gmail.com
```

`User_Store`

```
user_id     store_id
   1          1
   1          2
```

What does the user_store model contain relations whether it is belongstoMany or hasmany?

Answer (score 0):

You can use belongsToMany relationship

In your Store model define a method

```
   public function users() {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class, 'user_store', 'user_id', 'store_id');
        }
```

In your Users model define a method

```
 public function stores() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Stores::class, 'user_store', 'user_id', 'store_id');
}
```

Comment: Is this syntax is correct why we have user_id and store_id as parameters

Comment: Yes it is the correct syntax.
 
$this->belongsToMany( CLASS, TABLE, KEY-RELATING-THIS-MODEL, KEY-FOR-OTHER-MODEL )

For more Information please take a look of there links

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/204838/how-to-use-custom-pivot-tables-in-laravel-6-x

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you want a simple [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

For this you only need two models `User` and `Store`, you only need `StoreUser` if you want to do something special with the pivot table otherwise it is unnecessary.

The following would be the Laravel way:

**Table structure**

```
stores
    id
    name
    email
    phone 
    info

users
    id
    name
    email  

store_user
    user_id
    store_id
```

Laravel excepts the pivot table to be called `store_user`, you can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> To define this relationship, three database tables are needed: `users`,
> `roles`, and `role_user`. The `role_user` table is derived from the
> **alphabetical order** of the related model names, and contains the
> `user_id` and `role_id` columns.

**Model structure**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class);
    }
}


class Store extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```